# How to logout users after an AccessDenied exception? (Devise)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I have this in my application controller:

```
rescue_from CanCan::AccessDenied do |exception|
  redirect_to destroy_user_session_path, :method => :delete, :alert => exception.message
end
```

I want to logout the user once they try to open a resource they can't access.
But, the 'delete' method is not used, I get

```
No route matches [GET] "/authenticate/users/sign_out"
```

How to logout the user and show the login form (new_user_session)?

BTW The normal logout link works perfectly.

```
<%= link_to "Logout: #{current_user.name}", destroy_user_session_path, :method => :delete %>
```

Ace

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about?:

```
rescue_from CanCan::AccessDenied do |exception|
  sign_out :user if user_signed_in?
  redirect_to new_user_session_path, alert: exception.message
end
```

But IMHO it's not an expectable behaviour.

Comment: Great, that works! I understand what you mean with not expectable behaviour, but at least I know now how to do it. First sign the user out and then go wherever you want, right!? Thx!